# Category hierarchy in winforms PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have some properties that could be divided in categories and sub categories. When I add them to the PropertyGrid all subcategories are in the root, but i want sub categories to be children of categories.

```
class Settings
    {
        [Category("SubCategory1")]
        public bool Property1 { get; set; }

        [Category("SubCategory1")]
        public bool Property2 { get; set; }

        [Category("SubCategory2")]
        public bool Property3 { get; set; }
    }

PropertyGrid grid = new PropertyGrid();    
grid.SelectedObject = new Settings();
```

I want to make it look like

```
 -Category1
   -SubCategory1
      Property1
      Property2
   -SubCategory2
      Property3
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What code do you already have? If so, can you show some? ...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx

Comment: There is really nothing about hierarchy of Categories in this article. I found a control with a feature that I need. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/A4A710C1-7B90-4C36-A4FA-FF12B99B54C6. But I want to make nested Properties using standard PropertyEditor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a solution. The approach is to use TypeConverter Attribute and nested classes.

```
var settings = new Settings();
settings.Subcategory1 = new SubCategory1(){Property1 = "P1", Property2 = "P2"};
settings.Subcategory2 = new SubCategory2(){Property3="P3"};
grid.SelectedObject = settings;
```

...

```
public class Settings
{
    [Category("Category1")]
    public SubCategory1 Subcategory1 { get; set; }

    [Category("Category1")]
    public SubCategory2 Subcategory2 { get; set; }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof (ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class SubCategory1
{
    public String Property1 { get; set; }

    public String Property2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class SubCategory2
{
    public String Property3 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone.