# Can I change the displayed value of a category in a PropertyGrid (WinForm)?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, propertygrid

Property names can be changed with

```
[Category("Application"), DisplayName("Application"), Description("Application settings")]
```

But can I get rid of the class name in a category? I wish to display my own "string" there. I have tried `DisplayName` etc (see example class below), but no change.

Any idea? Besides `Application` I wish to see some description.

[image: Screenshot]

Example classes:

```
public class CSettings
{
    [Category("Application"), DisplayName("Application"), Description("Application settings")]
    public CApplicationSettings Application { get; set; } = new CApplicationSettings();

    [Category("Audio"), Display(Name = "Audio", Description = "Audio settings")]
    public CAudioSettings Audio { get; set; } = new CAudioSettings();
}
```

As you can see, also tried to apply it on "class level"

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
[Description("Application general settings")]
[DisplayName("General settings")]
public class CApplicationSettings
{
    [Description("Application Hotkeys")]
    [DisplayName("Hotkeys")]
    public CHotkeyList Hotkeys { get; set; } = CHotkeyList.DefaultHotykeys;
}
```

---

Related

- [Changing the PropertyGrid's Description and Category attributes at runtiome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24468820/356726)
- [How do I format/Alter displayed value in property grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39875274/356726)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397852/356726

Comment: 1) Override `CApplicationSettings`'s `ToString` method or 2) Create a custom `TypeConverter` (you can derive it from `ExpandableObjectConverter`), override `ConvertTo`, and return a string when `destinationType == typeof(string)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/241942/14171304

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will use my own converter if I do not find another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits/thanks to Simon Mourier and dr.null / Summary of their comments

1. Override `CApplicationSettings`'s `ToString` method or
2. Create a custom `TypeConverter` (you can derive it from `ExpandableObjectConverter`), override `ConvertTo`, and return a string when `destinationType == typeof(string)`. An example is the answer of [Property Grid on composite objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241887/356726) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/241942/356726